# How can I achieve the Japanese tatami mat layout pattern?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a layout HTML layout that follows the traditional Japanese tatami mat layout pattern.

[image: traditional tatami patterns]

I tried a table with rowspan and colspan. I get this far, but when I add the final colspan, the things collapses.

```css
td { 
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Also I would like to use a more flexible layout than tables if possible.

Comment: This is up to you, but in my opinion a [CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) would be (by far) the easiest way to create this sort of layout.

Comment: "When I add the final colspan" What is the final colspan? Which element are you talking about?

Answer (score 5):

Grid is definitely the way to go. Although it's more verbose, [grid-template-areas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas) is a good one as it allows you to visualise the layout in CSS. Use grid-auto-columns and grid auto-rows to set the size. I've used attribute selectors to keep the CSS short.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 5rem;
  grid-auto-rows: 5rem;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "a b b c c d"
    "a e f f g d"
    "h e i i g j"
    "h k k l l j";
}

.container > div {
  background-color: #DDD299;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

[a] { grid-area: a;}
[b] { grid-area: b;}
[c] { grid-area: c;}
[d] { grid-area: d;}
[e] { grid-area: e;}
[f] { grid-area: f;}
[g] { grid-area: g;}
[h] { grid-area: h;}
[i] { grid-area: i;}
[j] { grid-area: j;}
[k] { grid-area: k;}
[l] { grid-area: l;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div a></div>
  <div b></div>
  <div c></div>
  <div d></div>
  <div e></div>
  <div f></div>
  <div g></div>
  <div h></div>
  <div i></div>
  <div j></div>
  <div k></div>
  <div l></div>
</div>
```